# I need a C++ program to obtain the output into a .txt or .doc file?

Tags: c++

For Ex. Suppose I save a couple of nos. 21 and 42 stored into int a and int b respectively. I would like open an existing or a new .txt or .doc and print 21 and 42 in it. Is that possible?

Comment: _"Is that possible?"_ Of course it's possible. What a stupid kind of quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int a=21;
  int b = 42;
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << a << "\n" << b;
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read a little about handling file i/o in c++ before posting here.

Comment: Well, you should explain what your code actually does to some detail, when answering such a broad question. A code only answer, isn't so well achieved here.

Comment: Are you a Vlad sockpuppet?

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.